# A variant of quantum harmonic oscillators

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups, quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

We have the following variant of harmonic oscillators.

$$
\left\{  
\begin{array}{**lr**}  
T = a + a^\dagger\\
a | n \rangle  = \sqrt{[n]} |n-1 \rangle \\
a^\dagger |n\rangle = \sqrt{[n+1]} |n+1\rangle\\
[n] = \frac{1}{2}(\alpha\frac{1-q_1^n}{1-q_1} + \beta\frac{1-q_2^n}{1-q_2})
\end{array}  
\right.
$$

where $0<q_1,q_2<1$.

My question is how to calculate the quantity
$$
\langle n \mid T^k \mid m\rangle
$$

For the special case $\alpha = \beta =1, q_1 = q_2 = q$, this system becomes a *q-deformed harmonic oscillator*, which can be solved analytically.

Comment: Are you expecting a closed form for all $n,m,k$? For any given $n,m,k$, it's an elementary computation of course that you can teach a computer to do. Maybe that way you can see a pattern ...

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt I expect an analytical expression for $\langle n| T^k | m \rangle$. Just as we can get an analytical expression for $\langle n| x^k | m \rangle$ in a usual harmonic oscillator model.